# gdal2tiles finding unexpected state either way this GeoJSON is formatted

Tags: gdal, geojson, gdal2tiles

I am using gdal2tiles with a GeoJSON file to process. It is giving the following errors when trying to process the file below :

> ERROR 1: At line 29, character 16: Unexpected state: ',' or ']'
> expected

> ERROR 4: Failed to read GeoJSON data

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {"Data" : "0"},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -28.762207031249996,
              9.492408153765544
            ],
            [
              -28.591918945312496,
              9.492408153765544
            ],
            [
              -28.591918945312496,
              9.654907854199024
            ],
            [
              -28.762207031249996,
              9.654907854199024
            ],
            [
              -28.762207031249996, // This comma is causing the trouble somehow
              9.492408153765544
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That location is the comma in the final set of coords, but I thought that is required? If I remove the comma, I get the same error. What is happening?

Comment: Please include your gdal2tiles command [in your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/457483/edit) so we can test.

Comment: And can you also include a `gdalinfo` report on the raster you are using in the `gdal2tiles` command, so we can generate some test data that matches yours.

Comment: The error `Unexpected state: ',' or ']'` means that either comma or right square bracket is expected, but the parser sees something else. The geojsonlint.com site validates the  GeoJSON from your question (once the comment text is removed). Maybe you have some hidden characters in your real GeoJSON.